# Laplace transform of $F(t) = \begin{cases} t & 0 \le t < 1 \\ 2 - t & 1 \le t < 2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I am trying to find the Laplace transform of

$$F(t) = \begin{cases} t & 0 \le t < 1 \\ 2 - t & 1 \le t < 2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

My work is as follows:

$$\begin{align} \mathcal{L} \{ F(t) \} &= \int_0^1 t e^{-st} \ dt + \int_1^2 (2 - t)e^{-st} \ dt \\ &= \left\{ \left[ \dfrac{-1}{s} e^{-st} \times t \right]_0^1 + \dfrac{1}{s} \int_0^1 e^{-st} \ dt \right\} + \left\{ \left[ (2 - t) \times \dfrac{-1}{s} e^{-st} \right]_1^2 - \dfrac{1}{s} \int_1^2 e^{-st} \ dt \right\} \\ &= \dfrac{-1}{s}e^{-s} + \left[ \dfrac{-1}{s^2}e^{-st} \right]_0^1 - \dfrac{1}{s}e^{-s} + \left[ \dfrac{1}{s^2} e^{-st} \right]_1^2 \\ &= \dfrac{-1}{s}e^{-s} - \dfrac{1}{s^2}e^{-s} + \dfrac{1}{s^2} - \dfrac{1}{s}e^{-s} + \dfrac{1}{s^2}e^{-2s} - \dfrac{1}{s^2} e^{-s} \\ &= \dfrac{1}{s^2}e^{-2s} - \dfrac{2}{s^2}e^{-s} - \dfrac{2}{s}e^{-s} + \dfrac{1}{s^2} \end{align}$$

However, the solution is said to be $\dfrac{1}{s^2}(1 - e^{-s})^2$.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to review my work and help me find my error.

Comment: Shouldn't the the first integral in the second line go from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: You can use the Heaviside function to write your function as $f(t) = t + 2(1-t)H_1(t) - (2+t)H_2(t)$ and then apply the well-known property of the Laplace transform: $\mathcal{L}\{f(t-a)H_a(t)\} = e^{-as}F(s)$. Let me know if you would be interested in a full answer. Also, I would avoid the use of $\times$ as it can be misleading.

Comment: @celtschk I fixed that error, but I think that there is another. What do you think?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis This problem is from a section of the textbook that has not yet introduced the Heaviside function (that happens in the next chapter), so I would like to avoid it for this problem.

Comment: You have the sign flipped on this term: $\left[ (2 - t) \times \dfrac{-1}{s} e^{-st} \right]_1^2 = (2-2)\frac {-1}{s}e^{-2s} - (2-1)\frac {-1}{s}e^{-s} = \frac {1}{s}e^{-s}$

Comment: @DougM You're right! Thanks, Doug!